# Encrypted Shared preferences causes ANR on Android 9 and Android 10

Tags: android, encryption, android-anr-dialog, encrypted-shared-preference

I am using Encrypted shared preference to encrypted the preferences data. I am using it in the following way:

```
val masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(context)
                .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                .build()

        val sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                context,
                prefName,
                masterKey,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
        )
```

I accessing this securely shared preference instance from my application class. This is causing ANR issues in my production application.

```
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Native method)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:190)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block (CompletableFuture.java:1723)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock (ForkJoinPool.java:3446)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet (CompletableFuture.java:1752)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get (CompletableFuture.java:1923)
  at android.security.KeyStore.begin (KeyStore.java:1104)
  at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized (AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:248)
  at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit (AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider (Cipher.java:2984)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations (Cipher.java:2891)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider (Cipher.java:2796)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider (Cipher.java:773)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.init (Cipher.java:1143)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.init (Cipher.java:1084)
  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.encryptInternal (AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.java:84)
  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.encrypt (AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.java:68)
  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.validateAead (AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:248)
  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.getAead (AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:165)
  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.readOrGenerateNewMasterKey (AndroidKeysetManager.java:267)
  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.build (AndroidKeysetManager.java:236)
  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create (EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:160)
  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create (EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:120)
  at my.application.example.sharedpref.PrefProvider.getSecuredSharedPref (PrefProvider.java:15)
```

This behaviour observer majorly on Android 9 and 10.

There is Andorid bug reported around [cipher.init](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147384380?pli=1). Is there any way to solve this issue. It is causing bad behaviour for my application over playstore.

Comment: Hi Nilaksh. Have You find any fix or solution for this ANR? Please let me know If you can help me out.

Comment: No solution yet.

Comment: Android 11 too. still no solution

Comment: Any solution for this ?